Docker.service fails to start, error "overlay2: unknown option overlay2.override_kernel_check: overlay2"
I can't lift the service, the error always appears
journalctl -xe
-- The result is failed.
Apr 13 02:28:20 appserver systemd[1]: Unit docker.service entered failed state.
Apr 13 02:28:20 appserver systemd[1]: docker.service failed.
Apr 13 02:28:23 appserver systemd[1]: docker.service holdoff time over, scheduling restart.
Apr 13 02:28:23 appserver systemd[1]: Stopped Docker Application Container Engine.
-- Subject: Unit docker.service has finished shutting down
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
-- Unit docker.service has finished shutting down.
Apr 13 02:28:23 appserver systemd[1]: Starting Docker Application Container Engine...
-- Subject: Unit docker.service has begun start-up
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
-- Unit docker.service has begun starting up.
Apr 13 02:28:23 appserver dockerd[48633]: time="2024-04-13T02:28:23.209633101-05:00" level=info msg="Starting up"
Apr 13 02:28:23 appserver dockerd[48633]: time="2024-04-13T02:28:23.227671854-05:00" level=info msg="[graphdriver] trying configured driver: overlay2"
Apr 13 02:28:23 appserver dockerd[48633]: failed to start daemon: error initializing graphdriver: overlay2: unknown option overlay2.override_kernel_check: overlay2
Apr 13 02:28:23 appserver systemd[1]: docker.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Apr 13 02:28:23 appserver systemd[1]: Failed to start Docker Application Container Engine.
-- Subject: Unit docker.service has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
-- Unit docker.service has failed.
-- The result is failed.
Apr 13 02:28:23 appserver systemd[1]: Unit docker.service entered failed state.
Apr 13 02:28:23 appserver systemd[1]: docker.service failed.
Apr 13 02:28:25 appserver systemd[1]: docker.service holdoff time over, scheduling restart.
Apr 13 02:28:25 appserver systemd[1]: Stopped Docker Application Container Engine.
-- Subject: Unit docker.service has finished shutting down
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
-- Unit docker.service has finished shutting down.
Apr 13 02:28:25 appserver systemd[1]: start request repeated too quickly for docker.service
Apr 13 02:28:25 appserver systemd[1]: Failed to start Docker Application Container Engine.
-- Subject: Unit docker.service has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
-- Unit docker.service has failed.
-- The result is failed.
Apr 13 02:28:25 appserver systemd[1]: Unit docker.service entered failed state.
Apr 13 02:28:25 appserver systemd[1]: docker.service failed.
